# Unity -- JavaScript Car Going Wrong Direction

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a racing game and for it I modeled a car, obviously. Then after I finished all the car physics I decided to make a new car! So that's what I did. I put the car into the game, assigned the car movement script to it, attached the necessary components, rigidbody, collider, bumper prefs, etc... I tried to drive it but the car went sideways... I tried duplicating the car script and changing some statements but it didn't work. I tried going back to the model in Blender and rotating it by 90 degrees and when I loaded it up it didn't work.
Here is the movement code:

```
if(Input.GetAxis("Forward") && isMovingBackward == false) {

        if(lastDir == "backward") {

            deaccelerate();
            braking = true;
            canRotLeft = false;
            canRotRight = false;
        } if(!(lastDir == "backward") && canMoveForw == true) {

            lastDir = "forward";

            accelerate();

            isMoving = true;
            isMovingForward = true;
            isMovingBackward = false;
            canRotLeft = true;
            canRotRight = true;

            col();

            transform.Translate(Vector3(1, 0, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    if(!(Input.GetAxis("Forward"))) {

        isMovingForward = false;
    }

    if(!(Input.GetAxis("Backward"))) {

        isMovingBackward = false;
    }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Backward") && isMovingForward == false) {

        if(lastDir == "forward") {

            deaccelerate();
            braking = true;
            canRotLeft = false;
            canRotRight = false;
        } if(!(lastDir == "forward") && canMoveBack == true) {

            lastDir = "backward";

            accelerate();

            isMoving = true;
            isMovingBackward = true;
            ifMovingForward = false;
            breakingBack = false;
            canRotLeft = true;
            canRotRight = true;

            col();

            transform.Translate(Vector3(1, 0, 0) * -speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

If you need any more code just ask I'll provide it but don't expect the whole script because It's 500 lines long.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but, may be, `x`-`y` axis are started from left-upper corner, and you're thinking the something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You

## must work in z-forward in your modelling program

it's an absolute basic of the 3D industry that you **MUST WORK IN Z-FORWARD** when you model.

There is *no real way* to "fix" this.

You can *waste your time* or you can go back to blender and re-do it with z-forward.  Honest!

It's completely normal that a modelmaker builds something, and then it has to go back to be fixed because the person forgot to model it z-forward.

Particularly when you work on vehicles, *each little piece* must be z-forward.

For example, something that often catches people up is the left and right wheels/tyres must indeed individually be z-forward (you can't just "turn them around in the game").

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see. Thanks Joe, Id upvote if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if I ran into this kind of problems my exported models caused the issue.

You sad you tried to rotate it by 90 degrees in Blender. Have you also applied the rotation to the model?
If not, try rotating it again and press Ctrl. + A and apply the rotation and scale.

Comment: Id send you the image but I don't have 10 points. Basically in Blender on the right side on the yellow cube the z rotation is 90

Comment: Well, I can't say if that's correct without your script.
But another thing you could try is, making the car model a child of an empty object and placing the movement script on this parent-empty. That way you can rotate the car in unity until it fits independently of your movement script.

Comment: I believe Simon has hit the nail on the head - you have to "hit Ctrl-A" or whatever the command is in your modeling program, to "apply" rotation.